# PHP Symfony2 add 60 years to the both day Datetime object of a person

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, doctrine, entity

I need to add 60 Years to the date of birth of a person/worker, this person is stored in the database and I have the following code to define this person plus the getters and setters:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Worker")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Osd\RetireBundle\Entity\WorkerRepository")
 */
class Worker
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $idWorker;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
 */
private $omang;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $workerTitle;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $workerName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $workerSurname;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $birthDay;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $dateOfEmployment;
```

Inside this person/Worker, I do not really know is is correct to do it there, but I was trying to create a method like this:

```
    public function getRetireDate (){
   if($this->getBirthDay()) 
       return $retireYear = $this->getBirthDay()->add(new DateInterval('P60Y'));
}
```

I dont really know where to add the method?, but for now is inside the worker (Im new to symfony). but when ever I call it it gives me this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Osd\RetireBundle\Entity\DateInterval' not found in /var/www/Org/src/Osd/RetireBundle/Entity/Worker.php line 202
```

Any one who has done or knows how and where to achieve this feature?
Regards and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have sorted out the problem and your answer @david was really helpful; now my method looks like this:

```
public function getRetireYear (){
       return $this->retireYear = $this->getBirthDay()->add(new \DateInterval('P60Y'));
}
```

and I have a private var inside the Worker called $retireYear. that's it. It works wonderfully.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @vascowhite I'm really happy about the solution.

Comment: You can accept this answer, so that other uses know that you have found a solution.

Comment: Be careful and verify that the birth date itself is not getting 60 years added.  The add method is a bit unusual.  You probably want to clone the birth date then add.

Answer (score -1):

The `getRetireDate()` function is in `Worker` entity. The error that occur is probably you don't have `DateInterval` entity or you forget to include `DateInterval` entity to your `Worker` entity.

Comment: DateInterval is not an Entity in my Sumfony project. DateIntevel is and internal PHP Class I took it from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php). and I do not really know how does it work, is my first time using it. I'll keep researching any way. thank you. I'll post any progress.