# Symfony2 DateTime difference not working

Tags: php, datetime, symfony

I have this var in my twig templete:

```
{{aWorker.timeToRetirement|date('Y-m-d')}}
```

when I execute the page it's returning exactly this text: 'Y-m-d' without '' of course. Now what I really want to get is the difference between 2 dates, lets say a future date (is the retirement date of a person/worker you can get more info about what I'm doing if u need it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153540/php-symfony2-add-60-years-to-the-both-day-datetime-object-of-a-person/19154283#19154283)) '2060-12-01' and today's date '2013-10-03'. I want to do that using this var and method in my Entity class:

```
//...
//Var containing the retirement date
private $retireYear;
//var to store time to retirement from today
private $timeToRetirement;
//...
    public function getTimeToRetirement (){
        $this->timeToRetirement = $this->retireYear->diff(new \DateTime('today'));
    return $this->timeToRetirement;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? whay is the var not returning the difference between today and the retirement date

Answer (score 2):

Your function is returning a [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) object, so you need to use its [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method to generate your required string.

Comment: Totally right, thank you @vascowhite, I have changed the return to:


`code  return $this->timeToRetirement->format('%Y years, %m months, %d days');`
and the template var to: 
`code {{aWorker.timeToRetirement}}`
Thank you again. I don know how to put code on my coments the

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I'm learning how to do the comments now.